# Iterate through rows from Sqlite-query

Tags: android, sqlite, database-cursor

I have a table layout that I want to populate with the result from a database query. I use a select all and the query returns four rows of data.

I use this code to populate the TextViews inside the table rows.

```java
Cursor c = null;
c = dh.getAlternative2();
startManagingCursor(c);
// the desired columns to be bound
String[] columns = new String[] {DataHelper.KEY_ALT};
// the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry};

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
         R.layout.list_example_entry, c, columns, to);
this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I want to be able to separate the four different values of KEY_ALT, and choose where they go. I want them to populate four different TextViews instead of one in my example above.

How can I iterate through the resulting cursor?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use below code to go through cursor and store them in string array and after you can set them in four textview

```
String array[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];
i = 0;

cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    array[i] = cursor.getString(0);
    i++;
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I don't understand how I should use it. Should I still use the ListAdapter? Where do I specify the textviews each value should go to?

Comment: I got it working by skipping the ListAdapter and use a  mTv4.setText(ids[3]); to specify the value of each textview. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I faced the same issue , i did as you did but I forgot to increment i (i++) so only the first row is there !!!

Comment: sorry how do you initialize cur? I saw someone use Cursor cur = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME, null);
but I don't know sampleDB I don't know how to initialize sampleDB

Comment: I'd also check to make sure the cursor isn't null and that is has values (via the `.getCount()` method).  I still up voted though!

Answer (score 111):

`Cursor` objects returned by database queries are positioned ***before*** the first entry, therefore iteration can be simplified to:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // Extract data.
}
```

Reference from [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Comment: +1 Also `cursor.moveToPosition(-1)` will deal with shared cursors.

Comment: Exception raised if i want to iterate through rows and the rows contains join data

Answer (score 29):

```
for (boolean hasItem = cursor.moveToFirst(); hasItem; hasItem = cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // use cursor to work with current item
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Iteration can be done in the following manner:

```
Cursor cur = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME, null);
ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
if (cur != null) {
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            temp.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Title"))); // "Title" is the field name(column) of the Table                 
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am almost sure that your line `if (cur = null)` wasn't what you wanted to write... I guess it should be `if (cur != null)` instead. Also you are instantiating (and therefore overwriting) `temp` before you `add` things.

Comment: I also fixed the other part of the code. Hope you don't mind. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Found a very simple way to iterate over a cursor

```
for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){


    // access the curosr
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRowToString(cursor);
    final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree to chiranjib, my code is as follow:

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  do{
    //do logic with cursor.
  }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SQLfunction() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"column1","column2" ...};
    String sqlTable = "TableName";
    String selection = "column1= ?"; //optional
    String[] selectionArgs = {Value}; //optional

    qb.setTables(sqlTable);
    final Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

   if(c !=null && c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
           //do operations
           // example : abcField.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ColumnName")))

          }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }


}
```

NOTE: to use SQLiteQueryBuilder() you need to add

compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+' 
      in your grade file