# How to get columns data from sqlite database in ANDROID?

Tags: android, sqlite

i am working with sqlite database in Android for first time. i have create my database in Sqlite and copy it to androids `"data/data/App package/databases"`. i am able to copy and open database. i have four table in database i want `"State_Name(Column)" from "State_Master(Table)"`.

but i am not able to get any data(State name) from table.

Here i post my code:

```
//DataBase Helper

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private String[] stateArray;
private Context context;
private String DB_PATH;
private static String DB_NAME = "myDatabase.sqlite";
public static SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
public static final String STATE_NAME = "State_Name";

public LoveGodDB(Context context) throws Exception {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.context = context;
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if (dbexist) {
        opendatabase();
    } else {
        createdatabase();
    }

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(STATE_NAME);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void createdatabase() throws Exception {
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if (dbexist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copydatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
private boolean checkdatabase() throws Exception {
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    } catch (SQLiteException sle) {
        throw sle;
    }
    return checkdb;
}
private void copydatabase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myinput = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/"+ context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +"/databases/myDataBase.sqlite");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();
}
public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    LGDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}
public synchronized void close() {
    if (LGDataBase != null) {
        LGDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
public Cursor fetchAllTopics() {

    return LGDataBase.query("State_Master", new String[] {STATE_NAME}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
};


}
```

}

and my Activity where i want to store data in String Array:

```
public class MyStateGrid extends Activity{

private Button back;
private String[] stateNameArray ;
private GridView gridview = null;
private DatabaseHelper lgDB;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.errandboy_state);

    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    //stateNameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stateName);
    try {
        lgDB = new LoveGodDB(this);
        lgDB.opendatabase();
        Cursor c = lgDB.fetchAllTopics();
                    startManagingCursor(c); 
        stateNameArray = new String[]LoveGodDB.STATE_NAME};
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }finally{
        if(lgDB != null){
            lgDB.close();
        }
    }

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent stamp = new Intent(getParent(), xxxx.class);
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("Stamp", stamp);

        }
    });

    OnTouchListener backListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean  onTouch  (View  v, MotionEvent  event) {
            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    back.setOnTouchListener(backListener);
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return stateImageArray.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.galchild, null);
        ImageView stampImage;
        TextView stampName;
        stampImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        stampName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.stampName);
        stampImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        stampImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.stamps);
        stampName.setText(stateNameArray[position]);
        return v;
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestion?

Thanks...

Comment: could you post the logcat output showing the NullPointerException?

Comment: @vicki. thanks for reply, i am sorry i am not getting nullpointer regardig database. but in My stateNameArray i am getting just "State_Name(column name) String that i mention as a String in databaseHelper Class" instead of column data.

Comment: sorry I misread the question!  What is the line: `stateNameArray = new String[]LoveGodDB.STATE_NAME` meant to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand this line:

```
stateNameArray = new String[]LoveGodDB.STATE_NAME
```

try changing it to:

```
stateNameArray = new String[c.count()];
```

Then you need to put the state names in the Cursor into the String array:

```
int i = 0;
c.moveToFirst();
while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
    statNameArray[i]  = c.getString(0);
    i++;
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Answer adapted from: [Iterate through rows from Sqlite-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920528/iterate-through-rows-from-sqlite-query)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
return LGDataBase.rawquery("select STATE_NAME from State_Master", null);
```

*UPDATE*

You may need to loop through your cursor to get all the values out to an array like this: [How can I create a list Array with the cursor data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354006/how-can-i-create-a-list-array-with-the-cursor-data-in-android)

```
ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouWant> mArrayList = new ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouWant>();
for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); mCursor.moveToNext(); mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    // The Cursor is now set to the right position
   mArrayList.add(mCursor.getWhateverTypeYouWant(WHATEVER_COLUMN_INDEX_YOU_WANT));
}
```