# Return all data from a SQLite DB into two columns in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to return all data from my two column DB into two different `TextViews`. In one attempt, I can return all the data, but it's only in one `TextView`, in the second attempt, I can get it into the two `TextViews`, but it only returns the first row from the DB. First try:

```
    //--- Returns only first result

//--- DB Method
public String[] getPres2() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_PRES, KEY_YEAR};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String pstYr[] = new String[2];
        pstYr[0] = cursor.getString(0);
        pstYr[1] = cursor.getString(1);
        cursor.close();
        this.db.close();
        return pstYr;
    }
    return null;

}

//--- in the activity
public void DBMethod2() {
    dba = new DBAdapter(this);
    dba.open();
    String[] pst_Str = dba.getPres2();
    dba.close();
    pst_TV.setText(pst_Str[0]);
    yrs_TV.setText(pst_Str[1]);

}
```

and the second try:

```
    //--- Returns all results, but only in a single TextView
//--- DB Method
public String getPres3() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_PRES, KEY_YEAR};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iPrs = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRES);
    int iYr = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR);

    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result = result + cursor.getString(iPrs) + "\n" + cursor.getString(iYr) +   "\n" + "\n";
    }

    return result;

}


//--- In Activity
public void DBMethod3() {
    dba = new DBAdapter(this);
    dba.open();
    String pstY_Str = dba.getPres3();
    dba.close();
    pst_TV.setText(pstY_Str);

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt will work if you loop through all of the rows in the cursor.

[Here is an example from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920528/iterate-through-rows-from-sqlite-query)

```
 String arr[]=new String[4];
 i=0;

 cur.moveToFirst();
 while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) 
 {
     arr[i]  = cur.getString(0);
     i++;
     cur.moveToNext();
 }
```

Comment: I can't get your solution to work. First, it only returns the first DB row, and second, only the first TextView has a string in it, the second TextView is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the cursor, one row at a time, and then use the GetString syntax like this:

String mId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));

where COLUMN_ID is the name of the column in the sqlite database

Comment: I think what you're saying is this: `public String[] getPres() {
  String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_PRES, KEY_YEAR };
  Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,
    null);
  String result[] = new String[2];


  for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
   result[0] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRES));
   result[1] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR));
  }

  return null;

 }`

Comment: ...which I can't seem to get to work either. It's okay, though, because I've solved the problem another way. Rather than use a DB, I'm now creating a table and dynamically adding the rows which have the two columns in them.