# retrieve data from database (array) into textview

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

How to retrieve rows from external database and display them in text view??
i have tried some codes but the application stopped.

In my database helper i added that code :

```
public String[] getData(String l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { DB_ID, DB_name, DB_desc };
    // FILTERS DEPENDING ON THE CATEGORY TYPE PASSED IN THE PARAMETER
    Cursor c = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT _id,name,description FROM facilities WHERE name='" + l + "'", null);
    String[] result = new String[] { null, null, null, null, null };

    int iId = c.getColumnIndex(DB_ID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(DB_name);
    int iDesc = c.getColumnIndex(DB_desc);

    c.moveToFirst();

    result[0] = c.getString(iId);
    result[1] = c.getString(iName);
    result[2] = c.getString(iDesc);
    return result;
}
```

And this code in my activity which i wish to display the string in textview:

```
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        // dbhelper.open();
        String[] data =dbhelper.getData(namee);
        // dbhelper.close();
        txt.append("\n"+data[3]+"\n");}
     }
```

This is another code i tried it, from this url :
[Return all data from a SQLite DB into two columns in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099101/return-all-data-from-a-sqlite-db-into-two-columns-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the LogCat entries?
What does this line do?

```
String[] result=new String[]{null,null,null,null,null};
```

Try

```
String[] result = new String[5];
```

instead;

Answer (score 0):

I used this in one of my app.... This may help.

I declared the following in the main activity itself

```
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
.
.
try {
myDbHelper.createDataBase();
}
.
.
.
db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();// or db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
.
.
.
//In another function
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Whatever you want to query");
String[] s=new String[]{"The fields(columns) you want queried and used in textbox"};
```